# NSMutableArray only good for 25 items

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray which I use with UITableView. The strange issue I am facing is that

```
[results removeObjectAtIndex:rowIndexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

only works for the first 25 elements of the table, but crashes on the 26th? Nowhere in my code do I have any mention of 25 and I am at a loss why it does this.

All the elements display properly via UITableView so they have been inserted properly in the table.

Any help?

Comment: would be much easier to help if you said how it crashes

Answer (score 1):

Odds are that as you remove items from the index, you aren't reloading your table, so the rowIndexPath.row value isn't adjusted properly and you therefore run over the size of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

With `removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index`, you can see in documentation: **To fill the gap, all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index**. so you collapse elements, you can't iterate over the count of the array without updating the length, otherwise you will try to read an invalid index just because list collapsed by previous removes and it is shorter compared to what you expected.

Comment: But why do the the first 25 rows work, always? It's only row 26 which fails, consistently.The crash is at exactly that line when I try to delete the 26th row, not at the end of the array where I would expect trouble.

Comment: That may just be a specific case where you're referencing something out of bounds. Try this repeatedly by removing the element at index 0.
[results removeObjectAtIndex:0]; 
You should be able to remove all elements in your array like this. It should prove what Jack said

Comment: But length is aotomatically recalculated eact time it's required. I can continuousy remove elements at row 25 (if ther are more than 25 rows) with no problem.